# Managed Package - Access to Visualforce Page and Apex classes

Tags: managed-package, security, access

In my apex app, I have created multiple visualforce pages and Rest classes. This all looks good when the System administrator installs the package. However, user in the org can't access these pages and APIs as they don't have access to these.

For this, I think System administrator will have to manually go to each visualforce page and Rest classes in my app and give access to other profiles. I can include this in installation guide, but it seems very user unfriendly.

Isn't this a common problem? Is there a way I can assign access to these pages and classes to all profiles in the org?

Comment: yes, when installing select "all users". Also include perm sets to grant one offs as they arise

Comment: Thanks Eric, Now I got it. Please add your comment as answer so that I can accept.

Comment: done..............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes,

When installing

- select "all users".

Also include perm sets to grant one offs as they arise